# How to load data from Variable in eCharts

Tags: javascript, ajax, echarts

My problem is in displaying data, I cant display it at all.

When I write it like this it works  `"data: [5, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 5]"`

But when I use function to load and push data it display nothing. Data in console looks same to me `"[5, 0, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 5]"`.

```
  var f = document.getElementById("lineChart");
            new Chart(f, {
                type: "line",
                data: {
                    labels: ["3:00","6:00", "9:00", "12:00", "15:00", "18:00", "21:00", "24:00"],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: "Stress value:",
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.31)",
                        borderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                        pointBorderColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "rgba(38, 185, 154, 0.7)",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                        pointBorderWidth: 1,
                        data: (function (){
                                var res = [];
                                var len = 10;       

                                 $.ajax({         
                                  dataType:"JSON",            
                                  type: 'GET',
                                  url: "https://stressmonitor.smasty.net/api/1.0/day_stress/2017-02-26/?app_id=12345&token=12345"
                                 }).then(function(dataa) {

                                    var i= 0;
                                        while (len--) {
                                        console.log(res);
                                        res.push(dataa.intervals[i].value);
                                        i++;
                                        }
                                 });            

                            return res;
                         })()
                    }]
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: 5 lines up from the bottom you have a open and closing parenthesis () at the end, what are thet for? Try to remove that!

Comment: Problem was in asynchronous call, after i added PHP it worked.